# Specify which jQuery selector has priority over the others when separating them with commas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter, jquery-selectors

In jQuery, let's say I have the following JavaScript:

`$fooBar = $('a').filter('[href*="foo"], [href*="bar"]').first()`

And the following HTML:

```
<a href="bar.html">Bar</a>
<a href="foo.html">Foo</a>
```

Then `$fooBar` will return the `bar.html` link. But, in this case, because I specified that the `foo` selector comes first, I want `foo.html` to be returned instead. How can I make jQuery prioritize the results based on which selector comes first, rather than returning the results based on their location in the DOM?

Or is the only, true way to do this is to run each query with only one selector at a time, in order?

Comment: The order of elements in getting them with jQuery is based on the order of them in your HTML markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `filter` jQuery will find all matching elements in the [order the exist in the DOM.](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/). You could redo your code to first find the foo set then add the bar set, but you would have to implement something like in this example.

[How to preserve order of items added to jQuery matched set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281897/how-to-preserve-order-of-items-added-to-jquery-matched-set)

Comment: Thanks I guess that's good enough. I figured as much. I'll either use that method or just use a for loop and break out of it when I find the selector I want.